# Android: shortcut to move the elements in the xml layout in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I am using eclipse and I hate to use the mouse to place the elements as TextView, SmallButton, ToggleButton, etc. in the xml layout. Is there anyway to move these elements (to left, right, up and down) by using the shortcut?

The mouse is annoying me because when I try to place some elements they are often keeping getting stuck and tt is difficult for me to bring the elements to the right place.

Comment: Use the xml edit mode and use Ctrl+X, (arrow keys, page Up/Dn and/or other cursor moving key combinations), Ctrl+V - in Windows.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer but I tried it with Ctrl+V - in Windows and it does not work.

Comment: Ctrl+X = CUT, Ctrl+V = PASTE. You must have cut something, before pasting it somewhere else....